# How to confirm whether a device was fried by higher voltage

Tags: voltage, adapter

After a move, I inadvertently hooked up a 15V/3.42A adapter to a device—an X99 (RK3399) Android TV box—which I later found out (when it didn't turn on again)—on the web, as it's not indicated on the box—was rated for 5V/2A (or 3A, depending on the page). I then tried other fitting 5V adapters I had at home—one 1A and one 2.5A—and still no pulse (the box has a digital display). Is there a way of confirming whether I indeed fried the thing (like hooking up multimeters, or somethin')?

(Yes, I did search through the forum, and have read all cautions against using higher voltage adapters on electronics, but still... just wanted to know if there is an easy way to confirm before going about replacing it.)

Comment: If it does not function any more, isn't that a pretty good confirmation that it is broken? What other confirmation you would need? Have you opened the device and looked for molten or exploded parts?

Comment: AFAIK you already have your confirmation. It does not work anymore after connecting it to a far higher voltage than that it was designed for. Your only option, apart from replacing it, is now to look for broken components inside, which may or may not require a multimeter but might also require a skill level that you don't currently have.

Comment: Giving the device 300% of its rated voltage is all but guaranteed to destroy the circuitry. No manufacturer of consumer electronics is going to spend the extra cost to design it to take that much extra voltage. If it was 7.5 volts (150%) then maybe it would survive but not more.

Comment: It’s dead, Jim.

Comment: Probably no. But you could power it as intended and look at supply voltages inside derived from the power supply. If these are absent or wrong then the input regulators or converters are probably dead. This would be an indication that high Vin was the cause. BUT it is extremely likely that this IS the cause - but no simple action will confirm it with certainty.

Comment: @Justme There is a possibiliy—hope?—that the power adaptor wasn't working either (it's a got a led it's supposed to light up when connected to power outlet, but doesn't anymore either).

Answer (score 2):

> I inadvertently hooked up a 15V/3.42A adapter to a device—an X99 (RK3399) Android TV box... Is there a way of confirming whether I indeed fried the thing (like hooking up multimeters, or something)?

Probably no.

But you could power it as intended and look at supply voltages inside derived from the power supply. If these are absent or wrong then the input regulators or converters are probably dead. This would be an indication that high Vin was the cause.

BUT it is extremely likely that this IS the cause - but no simple action will confirm it with certainty.

Comment: If any parts are too hot to touch when powered up, that part is toast. And the whole box is fried Marshmellows.